# How do I generate automatic migration scripts with model-first?

Tags: entity-framework, migration

How do I generate automatic migration scripts with model-first in Entity Framework 4.3 or 5.0?

I've seen plenty of samples with this for code-first, but none that can be used in my scenario.

My problem is that I have a staging environment and a live environment. I may be making many model and database changes to the staging environment before publishing it all to the live environment.

This adds complexity when I then want to generate a migration script from my staging database to my live database.

Is this possible automatically somehow? Can this be achieved through the Entity Framework Power Tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code First Migrations, as you would expect from the name, currently only work with a Code First model. There are other tools, however, that may prove useful for your scenario like SSDT's [Schema Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272690.aspx) utility.